# Continuously display new content of a file that contains a given word

Tags: grep, logs, less

When using `less` pressing Shift-F takes to the end of the file, and continuously display new contents. Is there any option (with any *nix tool) to continuously display new content which contains a given string (e.g. look for a word `error`)?

As @Fedor Dikarev pointed out in comments `tail -f /var/log/program.log | grep error` allows for that. However, is there any option to look for a string and have a possibility to change word to be searched for? `grep` won't allow for that.

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/program.log | grep error`

Comment: Thanks! Is there an option to change the word to be searched for dynamically? `grep` won't allow for that.

Comment: @menteith Re-execute the pipeline with a new word would do that. What do you mean?

Comment: @Kusalananda Sorry, I don't think I know what you mean.

Comment: If you re-ran the `tail -f` + `grep` pipeline with a new word, that would look for that new word instead.  What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: With `less` you can search for one word and then search for another. This is what I meant by "dynamically".